How to put equal sign into a table in libreoffice writer?
I need to put an equal sign into a table in libre office writer. Just equal sign, nothing more
=
Unfortunately, Writer tries to interpret it as a formula (or doing something else weird I don't know what) and I don't know how to turn this mode off.
Is it possible?

How can I put = into a table in LibreOffice writer without triggering a formula?
The following two options work for me:

Copy and Paste - to insert = from the clipboard, or

Type space= and then delete the space



I get the same result as asked in this question.
As an alternative, insert the equal size as a special character.
That would be Insert -> Special Character -> then select the equal sign from the list of possible special characters.
